# Embed Youtube player in Android App (android studio in java)

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

**Quick Background:** I'm building an English learning app for adults and aged people to learn accents and improve vocab. I  want to embed a reels like immersive video player which shows only yt shorts from an account which is only used by this app (for better suggestions of shorts)

So is it possible to embed video and link *upvote downvote* buttons to *like dislike* buttons and sync comments. I couldn't find anything relevant except for a [deprecated SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player). And the [new SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) it refers to uses html (I think). Should I use WebView something like Amazon does?